# Как узнать какие элементы были изменены функцией?

Tags: c++, windows, память, виртуальная-память, системное-программирование

Задача может показаться странной, но у нее есть практическое применение.

Задан достаточно большой массив, который в цикле постоянно изменяется функцией ChangeValue, которая может изменить в этом массиве как один элемент, так и несколько. Также она может ничего не менять.

Требуется внешними (относительно функции ChangeValue, сама функция для нас черный ящик) средствами определить какие элементы были изменены.

Прошу подсказать любые идеи по реализации такого отслеживания, за исключением тривиального варианта - сравнения значения массива до и после функции, это слишком медленно.

Реализуемо ли:

Отслеживание на уровне системных страниц?

Передача в функцию имитатора изменяемого массива?

Запуск в виртуальной среде?

и т.д.

Ниже приведен пример программы:

```
    void ChangeValue(int * values) {
    // работает как черный ящик
    // мы не знаем ТОЧНО какие элементы меняет эта функция
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR, int)
{
    while (true) {
        int values[100000000] = {0};
        ChangeValue(values);
        // здесь требуется узнать какие элементы были изменены
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну да, под отладчиком VS2017 в пошаговом режиме Вам покажут, какие элементы были изменены. Но только вряд-ли отладчик VS2017 потянет массив целых размером в сто миллионов. :-)

Comment: *"у нее есть практическое применение"* - какое? Пока это похоже на проблему XY.

Comment: @VTT видимо, reverse engineering и кулхацкерный взлом суровых закрытых алгоритмов.

Comment: @VTT, bipll, да, это связано с reverse engineering, но это не кулхацкерный взлом

Comment: @Abyx, спасибо за подсказку про PAGE_GUARD. Можете дать приблизительную оценку по времени, насколько это быстрее или медленнее, чем сверка значений массива до и после функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAGE_GUARD - хорошее решение. В случае, если в массиве изменяется не более 10% данных перехват исключений, связанных с PAGE_GUARD дает двукратное увеличение скорости.

Правильный же ответ: пользоваться функциями GetWriteWatch и ResetWriteWatch. Это предоставляемый системой способ отслеживания изменения памяти на уровне страниц.
Работает максимально быстро.

Comment: В описании `GetWriteWatch` сказано: "_This address must be in a memory region that is allocated by the VirtualAlloc function using MEM_WRITE_WATCH_". Как ее можно использовать для отслеживания изменений в чужом адресном пространстве при таком условии?

Comment: Перечитал еще раз свой вопрос, я точно в нем никаким образом не писал, что мне нужно отслеживать изменения в чужом адресном пространстве, я указал, что изменяющая функция работает для нас в режиме черного ящика. GetWriteWatch хороша для работы сборщика мусора, например, но не подходит для работы в чужом адресном пространстве.